# How to create a stream graph with non-spatial data

Tags: qgis, r

The raw data would be like this: [image]

I want to create a streamgraph with the width of the polygon being the amount in the certain date for the certain purpose, the output should be in shapefile format :

[image]

I don't know whether the transformation can be done with QGIS or ArcGIS, or I have to process the raw data with R

Comment: I'd say that's what plots are for and *R* might just be the ultimate tool for them. anyways, a *shapefile* seems to be among the very last file types to go for. do you want to overlay that graph along a stream/road network?

Comment: You *could* do this in QGIS but it would require some Python coding - the same probably applies to ArcGIS as well.

Comment: Might be possible with the variable width buffer tool in QGIS. You would need to first create a line, divide it into segments, and join the raw data table to the line segments.